# A problem about golang concurrency in once

Tags: go, concurrency

I am reading the official document, there is a code that I can't understand.

```golang
var a string
var done bool

func setup() {
    a = "hello, world"
    done = true
}

func doprint() {
    if !done {
        once.Do(setup)
    }
    print(a)
}

func twoprint() {
    go doprint()
    go doprint()
}
```

> This version can (incorrectly) print an empty string instead of "hello, world".

Why this code may produce wrong results.

Comment: Where is this code from? It does not make sense - `once` is nowhere declared for a start.

Comment: @AJR The code is taken from [The Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem), and `once` is an instance of `sync.Once`. The stress is on the incorrect synchronization.

Comment: @icza in that context I get it.  The confusing thing is that particular problem is a data race on `done` and not really to do with `once`.  BTW I upvoted your answer and deleted my stupid one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in `doprint()` the `done` variable is is accessed (read) without synchronization.

Imagine the first goroutine running `doprint()` completes before the second is scheduled to run. The first writes `done` (in `setup()`), and the 2nd goroutine tries to read `done`: should that read produce the result written by the first goroutine? There is no synchronization: undefined behavior. It may be that `done` will be observed as `true`, and thus `setup()` will not be called, and it may be the write to `a` will not be observed and thus the initial zero value (empty string) is printed.

Reads of variables always observe previous writes (previous in time) in a *single* goroutine. Writes made by a goroutine are not guaranteed to be observed in another goroutine unless there is synchronization between them.

Answer (score 0):

Just to further explain the accepted answer, in Go, compilers and processors may reorder reads/writes. In a single go routine, such reordering is guaranteed to not affect the behavior.

However, in your example, there are multiple go routines without synchronization and reordering DOES have an impact. Imagine the first go routine executes `done=true` then `a=xxxx`, if the second go routine executes after first `done=true` and before `a=xxxx`, it will produce an empty string.